MySQL blocked while using select for update
I have two windows In the first window I type:
- begin;
- select * from users where pid = 100 for update;

This is actually not able to query the data, so no lock is generated.
In the second window I type:
- select * from users where pid = 1 for update;

It's stuck in the second window, too. Why?
After typing commit; in the first window, the second window continues.
So what is meaning of Row-Level-Lock? I'm confused.
The following gives more information:
The MySQL table index:
> show index from users;
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| users |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |       14754 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| users |          1 | pid         |            1 | pid         | A         |       14754 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |

Using EXPLAIN
> explain select * from users where pid=1;
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | pid           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 15204 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+

> explain select * from users where id=18035;
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+

Why the table index contains pid, but the EXPLAIN shows the key is NULL

According to the docs: "For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries" - at a guess pid is not an indexed column, therefore the first query is doing a clustered index scan to find pid = 100, and in doing so encountered the row pid = 1 and subsequently locked it, even though it didn't ultimately return it. This is discussed in much more detail within answers to this question

I tested this, and I cannot reproduce. The second window does not wait if I query for pid = 1. I suggest that it isn't the first window that has that row locked, but another session.

I have added more information about the table. The pid is an indexed column. And when I try to use select * from users where id = 100 for update;, it is not blocked. What is the difference?

@BillKarwin When I type commit in the first window, the second window continues. So I guess there is no other session

“This is actually not able to query the data”: why not?
